# App crashed when installed from APK in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, apk, sqlite-net

App crashed when installed from APK ,but runs fine when connected via USB from Visual Studio.

I'm using Visual Studio Xamarin Forms with C#, I'm getting the data from an API and a database located on a server. I tested an apk and it worked fine.

**When it stopped working:**
Now I have made some changes, because my app has to simulate working the same when there's no internet connection, so I implemented SQLite using nuget sqlite-net-pcl. So when my app has internet connection, the app will store some values in local database, and if at any moment detects no internet will go and take the lastest info from the local database. I have been testing using my phone connected via USB and works great.

**Problem:**
So I created the Apk file again and after installing it shows data from the API, but when I clicked the first button it crashes or just closes without any message.

**My code:** I don't know what can be really usefull here but basically this is my local database connection (this code line appears in every page):

```
private SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "LocalDB.db3"));
```

This is an example of how I insert and get data from the local database:

```
    private void InsertPisterosLocal()
    {
        //first delete table data
        //db.DeleteAll<T_Pisteros>();
        db.DropTable<T_Pisteros>();
        db.CreateTable<T_Pisteros>();

        foreach (var item in PisterosLista)
        {
            var DatosRegistro = new T_Pisteros
            {
                PisteroID = item.PisteroID,
                PisteroN = item.PisteroN
            };
            var num = db.Insert(DatosRegistro);
        }
    }

    public void GetPisterosLocal()
    {
        try
        {
            db.CreateTable<T_Pisteros>();
            List<T_Pisteros> PisterosLista = new List<T_Pisteros>();
            PisterosLista = db.Table<T_Pisteros>().ToList();
            pck_Pisteros.ItemsSource = PisterosLista;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And this is the manifest (again I don't know if can be of any help):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.gearsofsoftware.servlottery" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="Premios Servicentro" android:icon="@mipmap/icon"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

I'm really praying someone can help me here, I feel like this is a dead end for me, I have no clue what to do :(

Comment: you are just catching exceptions and throwing them again, which will crash the app.  Instead display an error message with the exception detail so you know what is happening.  You can also use a crash reporting too like appcenter.ms to track details of crashes

Comment: I don't think is related at all, those exceptions are only trigger when no internet connection, but I'm working with internet, so the code doesn't even go there yet, but still fails

Comment: GetPisterosLocal doesn’t appear to do anything with the network.  Regardless, you should add exception handling to any suspect code and log the exceptions or output them.  Or use a crash tool as I suggested

Comment: This is the call to GetPisterosLocal, as you can see gets triggered only if there's no internet: var task = App.CheckIfInternet();
            task.Wait();
            connected = task.Result;
            if (connected == true)
            {
                pck_Pisteros.ItemsSource = await GetTasksAsync(); 
            }
            else
            {
                GetPisterosLocal();
            }

Comment: Please pay attention to the larger point I’m making about exception handling.

Comment: You’re also missing the internet permission from your manifest

Comment: you mean something different than <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Comment: You should run `adb logcat` in your terminal to figure out what the exception is https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat . Without the exception, you are just playing a guessing game

Comment: @Saamer I got the logcat, but I dont really understand what's going on :/

Comment: Haha no problem. Put it in a pastebin and Share the link. you basically have to look for any errors or exceptions

Comment: WOW MAN WOW! I checked the logcat throughtly (literally for hours haha) and then found and the error was that couldn't found a table, I just replaced DeleteAdd<Table> for DropTable<Table> before doing this CreateTable<Table> and that made it work :D

Comment: Great job finding the solution yourself, that's always the best way to learn! Share the logcat stuff anyway and answer the question below and accept. That way if there are others that have the same problem, they can use this to figure out their solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install ADB and the ran logcat

Here are the logs: https://pastebin.com/304eFXMq

Basically the key line was:
"SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: T_Promo"

I thought no calls to the local database had to be done at that point, a call was being made as starting the second page (when it crashed) and this call has the following code:

```
db.DeleteAll<T_Promo>();
db.CreateTable<T_Promo>();
```

I changed it to

```
db.DropTable<T_Promo>();
db.CreateTable<T_Promo>();
```

and now is working fine.